# Laravel(500- Internal server error): Unable to get data from model to controller

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to list a dropdown in the index page with data from database. I created a model and made some changes in controller to display it in my view page but making any change in the controller gives a blank page with 500 Internal server error in the console. Please help me out to sort this problem.

> Table name: walker_type
>
> Routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'WebController@index');
```

> Model: ProviderType.php :

```
<?php

class ProviderType extends Eloquent {
  protected $table = 'walker_type';
}
```

> Controller: WebController.php

```
 public function index() {
    $walkerTypeList = ProviderType::all();
    return view('website.index')->with(['walkerTypeList' => $walkerTypeList]);
}
```

> View:index.php

```
@foreach ($walkerTypeList as $car)
  <option data-icon="glyphicon-road" value="{{ $car->name }}"> {{ $car->name }} </option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please check your error logs what is causing the 500 errors. If you are running the code on a developer machine, you can also enable debugging to show error messages instead of the 500 page. Just from quickly glancing at your code snippets, my initial assumption is that you are missing the use statement for the SoftDeletingTrait in your WalkerType, but better look at the error message to be sure.

Comment: did you try with `with('walkerTypeList', $walkerTypeList);` ?

Comment: `dd($walkerTypeList)` in your controller before you return the view,  to see if it is being populated first.

Comment: @dbrumann I found one of my mistake. There was already an existing model for the same table name ProviderType. So I just replaced the model name with the same inside the index function in controller.. Then debugging it showed the results.. But I am still unable to pass the variable to view.

Answer (score 0):

Had u declare your model below your namespace?

eg. `use App\WalkerType;`

also you forgot to declare a namespace to your Model.

it should have `namespace App;`

or if you have a folder for your model to make it more conventional.

you should have a namespace on each of your model.

eg. `App\Model`

and then use that in every controllers by declarin in between your namespace and class

eg.

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Model\WalkerType;

class SomeController extends Controller{
     protected $data;  //this is a class variable that can call anywhere to your class by calling it this way $this->data

     public function some_method(){

         $this->data['variable_a'] = "some_value"; //this can call in you view later by $variable_a

        $this->data['sum'] = 1+4; //result can be display in your view by calling the variable $sum

         return view('someview',$this->data);
     }


}
```

I hope this can help you for your project efficiently, cause we had experienced that we forgot to include some of the data that has been processed on the controller and needed to display in  your view file but forgot to include.

Comment: I am getting the result in controller when debugging but unable to pass it to the view page.

Comment: i'll edit my answer you can have an overview on how i transfer the data on the view file.

Comment: can u try the View::make('someview') method

Comment: When i write : return View::make('website.index'); it works
but return view("website.index")->with(["walkerTypeList" => $walkerTypeList]); gives error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160269/discussion-between-kenneth-sunday-and-debs).

Comment: Do i have to change something in the routes? Here it is : Route::get('/', 'WebController@index');